# VBA Formatting to Highlight Text Based on Checkbox

Tags: excel

I've got another question regarding the use of checkboxes and highlighting values based on if a box is checked or not.

Looking at the image below, I would like to highlight the number above a checkbox if it is checked.

This one is a bit tricky since the numbers are all inserted text boxes within the same cell as the checkboxes so the vba formula would have to associate each checkbox with its correct text box number above it and then change the fill color to yellow if the box is checked.

Any help would be much appreciated as this is definitely beyond my current capability of vba coding :)

[image]

Comment: You should at least make some effort - I doubt anyone will code the whole thing for you. Linking the checkbox and textbox names would be a useful start.

Comment: Thanks SJR, but I got the help I needed. I'm just learning VBA and am not very good at it yet. The code I needed was quite simple and I just needed a push in the right direction with showing me how to do the first one and I could figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   If Me.CheckBox1.Value Then
      Me.Shapes("TextBox 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
   Else
      Me.Shapes("TextBox 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
   End If
End Sub
```